# What are some cheap 8-10 inch displays?

Tags: display, e-ink

I am looking for a display that is 8-10 inches across diagonally, low power, preferably colour and refresh rate isn't an issue.  I would want to display text on it, so I need something with a decent resolution.
I was thinking monochromatic e-ink / e-paper would be the best option, but it looks like they can be quite expensive.  Anyone know of some cheap displays that I could use for a project?

Comment: Seems like you have a clear idea of what you want, so we can't help you further. Shopping questions are too localized to be helpful to others

Answer (score 2):

I've wanted to do research on this a few years ago too. At the time development kits including 2 displays cost up to 5000 dollar.

If you can live with a bit smaller dimensions your cheapest option may be to cannibalize a [Kindle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0051QVESA). Six inch for only 79 dollar.
I own one and it has excellent resolution, under a jeweller's magnifier it looks like paper.

Color e-ink displays are not common yet, and may be prohibitively expensive. I would stick to grayscale.

Comment: Agreed. The Kindle is probably the cheapest solution. Cheaper than buying just a single display, anyway.

Comment: Has anyone reverse-engineered the interface to the kindle display? I remember that early e-paper screens had big custom ASICs controllers, so the actual display may need a *lot* more then just your common pixel/row control signals. It's possible the display controllers have moved to the display module, rather then the main kindle PCB as of late, but I have not seen a teardown of them recently.

Comment: Ok, yeah. The screen from the kindle needs to be driven by a specialized ASIC. In the kindle 2, at least, it's the [S1D13521](http://vdc.epson.com/index.php?option=com_docman&task=cat_view&gid=289&Itemid=99). Note that it's **only** available in 181 or 180 ball PFBGA packages, and the datasheet is only available (I believe) under NDA. Realistically, I think the kindle screen is really not an option, unless you use the *whole kindle* as your screen. It does run linux, so you may be able to use the whole, integrated device as a screen, and talk to the kindle's MCU over serial, or something.